# Legrand Orange Book template Example colorbox from black to ocre

Tags: environments, book-design

In the Legrand Orange Book template, I would like to change the begin and end of the Example Box color from black to ocre:

[image]
and

[image]

Here is the code from the structure.tex file where the example environment is found:

```
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}

% Creates an environment for each type of theorem and assigns it a theorem text style from the "Theorem Styles" section above and a colored box from above
\newenvironment{theorem}{\begin{tBox}\begin{theoremeT}}{\end{theoremeT}\end{tBox}}
\newenvironment{exercise}{\begin{eBox}\begin{exerciseT}}{\hfill{\color{ocre}\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}\end{exerciseT}\end{eBox}}               
\newenvironment{definition}{\begin{dBox}\begin{definitionT}}{\end{definitionT}\end{dBox}}   
\newenvironment{example}{\begin{exampleT}}{\hfill{\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}\end{exampleT}}    
\newenvironment{corollary}{\begin{cBox}\begin{corollaryT}}{\end{corollaryT}\end{cBox}}
```

Can you tell me how to make the change?

Comment: for the end see exercise, for the begin we need the code of eBox environment

Comment: I think the `\color{ocre}` must be placed between the two `\begin{...}\begin{...}`, not in the inner, but this a guess. As touhami said: Without code we don't know what the environments do actually. According to the tags `tcolorbox` is used, but there's no direct indication

Comment: And by the way: I asked you multiple times to provide compilable examples, but here is again a pure fragment almost nobody can work with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `example` environment uses a `exampleT` environment defined as a theorem-like structure with style `blacknumex` which adds the little square at the beginning. You can define a similar style `blacknumexocresq` with the square in ocre color and an `exampleM` structure using this style. The redefine `example` to use `exampleM` instead of `exampleT` (or define another environment using `exampleM`):

```
\documentclass{book}
\input{structure}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{blacknumexocresq}% Theorem style name
{5pt}% Space above
{5pt}% Space below
{\normalfont}% Body font
{} % Indent amount
{\small\bf\sffamily}% Theorem head font
{\;}% Punctuation after theorem head
{0.25em}% Space after theorem head
{\small\sffamily{\textcolor{ocre}{\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}}\nobreakspace\thmname{#1}\nobreakspace\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{}\@upn{#2}}% Theorem text (e.g. Theorem 2.1)
\thmnote{\nobreakspace\the\thm@notefont\sffamily\bfseries---\nobreakspace#3.}}% Optional theorem note
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{blacknumexocresq}
\newtheorem{exampleM}{Example}[chapter]

\renewenvironment{example}{\begin{exampleM}}{\hfill{\textcolor{ocre}{\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}}\end{exampleM}}        

\begin{document}

\begin{example}{My text}
Some test text goes here to illustrate the use of the box defined for text to illustrate the use of the box defined for text to illustrate the use of the box defined for text.
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]